# Joining two tables, one of which containing the other

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am new in the SQL world (my problem might be very easy to solve).
Also,I work exclusively on Access.

I'm french and I realise that it is hard for me to explain so I'll give you a demo after.
I have two tables, A and B.
Both have a column id and all of the id of B are in A (but B has different columns however)
I'd like to join them, based on the id of course, to obtain a table containing A plus B  when there is a matching id.
Therefore result must have the exact number of rows as table A.

```
Table A
id - value1 - value2
1      0.5      0.6
2      0.4      0.9
3      0.4      1
4      0.8      1

Table B
id - name1 - name2
1     az      at
4     df      ml

Result:

id- value1- value2 - name1- name2
1    0.5     0.6       az    at
2    0.4     0.9
3    0.4      1    
4    0.8      1        df    ml
```

When an element of A is not in B, I still need to have them in the result, with a null value in the columns where the information is missing.
If you don't understand my english, just look at the demo, it's self explanatory

I tried to code a FULL OUTER JOIN by myself (because it doesn't exist in Access) but the result I get is a table with a lot of duplicates.
I also tried a lot of JOINs but I always get a table with a lot more rows than A

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use left outer join

Comment: Hi. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Eg: Googling even 'site:stackoverflow.com sql join result, with a null value in the columns where the information is missing' gives question titles where it is clearly expected that a thing called "left join" should return nulls. Also, if you had read the section on any introduction to all joins then you would have found left outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a left join here:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.value1,
    a.value2,
    b.name1,
    b.name2
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.id = b.id;
```

A left join would guarantee that every row in `TableA` would appear in the result set, even if a given row's `id` value did not match to anything in `TableB`.

If you don't want `NULL` to possibly appear for the `name1` and `name2` fields for those records where there was no match, then consider using `Nz(name1, '')` to show empty string instead.

Comment: I can't address your comment without seeing your actual data.  My answer should be correct, based on the small set of sample data you did show us.